# .NET ActiveX interoperability issue

Tags: .net, video, interop, activex

I've downloaded a commercial ActiveX control (a video player), which unfortunately wasn't tested in .NET environment. 
The control demo functions flawlessly. It's also perfectly reusable in legacy Visual Basic 6 environment. But when I try to use this control in .NET (WinForms) environment, I get a blank screen and no sound instead of video playback. No errors occur in the control, though, the screen is just blank.
Both VB6 and .NET executables run in x86 mode, so that's not an issue. I've also tried creating an ActiveX control wrapper in VB6 and adding it to .NET project, but got the same results.

UPDATE: the issue seems to be in the rendering mode. The control has a property named `VideoDriver` with default being `vdGDI`. When the mode is set to `vdDirectDraw`, it plays but periodically crashes. It's weird because I thought the idea of ActiveX is to work in any environment that supports this technology.

Any hints on getting it to work?

Comment: Is your .NET application written in WPF or in WinForms?

Comment: You bought a pig in a poke.  There's little point continuing to waste your time on it, embed Windows Media Player instead.  Right-click the toolbox, Choose Items, COM tab.

Comment: I haven't bought it yet, just a trial version... I know about WMPlayer, but the point is codec-independence. The control is an FFMPEG wrapper - it works without any codecs installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I've seen issues like this before w/ active x controls.  The only hack I know of is to wrap it in a vb 6 control then host that control in .net.  Total hack but unless the control is walking the control stack and trying to cast them to an inappropriate types it should work.

Comment: I've already tried wrapping the control as described in my post.